# Unable to Save AFNetworking responseObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, afnetworking

I'm calling a web service using `AFNetworking` and saving the return data in `NSDictionary` object. But nothing's being stored in it, even when data is successfully logged in `NSLog()`.

This is my dictionary:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *newsItems;
```

and this is my codes:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"key": @"keyy", @"q": @"ads" };
    [manager POST:BaseURLString parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        self.newsItems = (NSDictionary *) responseObject;
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```

Comment: Your code is correct, can you put a `NSLog` for `self.newsItems` along with `responseObject`?

Comment: It may return with `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`. Check response type before cast it.

Comment: Please post the NSLog for `responseObject` in console.

Comment: It is supposed to return array of dictionaries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check whether you're getting any response from web service using the below line:

```
NSLog(@"RESPONSE : %@", operation.responseString);
```

Second, if your web service is supposed to return an array of dictionaries, then you should declare an array instead on dictionary.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *newsItems;
```

instead of

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *newsItems;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare an `NSArray` & not `NSDictionary` like following:

`@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *newsItems;`

And assign `responseObject` like following:

`self.newsItems = (NSArray *) responseObject;`

Hope this helps.